# Unable to replace spree default logo in spree 2.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Used firebug and inspected Spree default logo is coming from
*`/assets/store/logo.png`*

Checked in spree 2.1.3 Version Source code and found default logo is coming from /logo section.

path :

```
core/app/models/spree/app_configuration.rb

preference :logo, :string, default: 'logo/spree_50.png'
```

Trying to Override, the default logo using Spree:Config option.

```
Spree::Config.set(logo: "store/logo.png")
```

But it's still redirecting to the old image(spree_50.png) and I am unable to replace the default logo.

Answer (score 8):

In application.rb:

```
Spree.config do |config|
# Example:
# Uncomment to override the default site name.
# config.site_name = "Spree Demo Site"

config.logo = "logo.png"

end
```

Then add your logo to public/images/ and the logo will show up.

Comment: This should be in `config/initializers/spree.rb`. Works perfectly there. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can place your image at this path.

**Inside: app/assets/images/logo/"Your Image"**

for eg.  app/assets/images/logo/hi5_logo.png**

**Inside: config/initializers/spree.rb**

```
Spree.config do |config|
        config.logo = "logo/hi5_logo.png"  #for default store logo
        config.admin_interface_logo = "logo/hi5_logo.png" #for admin logo
    end
```