# Spree 2.1.3 unable to change default logo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am using spree 2.1.3 and I can't manage to change the default logo. I have tried adding it in app/assets/images/admin/bg/spree_50.png but no luck.

I have tried the following : [Unable to replace spree default logo in spree 2.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323347/unable-to-replace-spree-default-logo-in-spree-2-1-3)

this user had the same problem I am having, however the answer did not work. my first solution probably worked in spree 1.3, but it is not working with the current stable version and I can't find a solution anywhere. Spree's official documentation still uses the first thing i tried so I am assuming that they did not update this.

Anyone knows what i need to do here ?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SO post you referenced says to add the config settings in config/application.rb, but I think it needs to be in config/initializers/spree.rb.

For example,

```
Spree.config do |config|
  # Example:
  # Uncomment to override the default site name.
  # config.site_name = "Spree Demo Site"
  config.admin_interface_logo = 'logo/some_other_logo.png'
  config.logo = 'logo/this_logo.png'
end
```

In a fresh installation of Spree 2.1.3 with Rails 4, the above was enough for me to change the location for the logo in both the admin interface and for the rest of the store. Hope that helps!

Comment: It worked flawlessly, however I do have one final question. How do I style an image if I called it in spree.rb ? I'm new to this and I have little knowledge in the actual Ruby language.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. Can you clarify what you mean by "style an image?" With CSS? Or do you mean how to use a particular paperclip style with it?

Comment: Well, the image .png image i am loading appears in it's full size. Usually, I would just give it a width and height in the CSS so that I can control that, however I don't see how I can do this here since I did not give the image a style and I cannot wrap it in a div. I am very new to "deface".

Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha. Easiest would be if you could use the existing markup to target the logos. For the admin logo, `body.admin #logo` should be sufficient. For the storefront logo, `#logo` should suffice. If that's not good enough, you would need to use a Deface override to change the markup.

Comment: Is the documentation wrong? It says "For example, to replace the Spree logo you would simply copy your logo to: your_app/vendor/assets/images/logo/spree_50.png." in the Asset Customization Documentation, https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/asset.html.